# Php function that takes SQL query as a parameter and returns JSON string

Tags: php, json

This is my function so far, how do I convert the item to json and print it?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM department';
function dataGenerator($query) {
$conn = oci_new_connect('u','p','h') or die ("dbdn");
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$r = oci_execute($stid);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print ($item); }
}
}
dataGenerator("SELECT * FROM department");
```

Comment: What have you tried? Nothing in your function suggests you're attempting to create a JSON string.  For example, have you looked up `json_encode`?

Comment: `print (json_encode($item));`

Comment: @J.Litvak that wont work well inside that loop ;)

Comment: Just from a coding point of view - make the database connection outside the function (better to make 1 connection per page) and pass in as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_encode` and your function should have a return

```
function dataGenerator($query) {
$conn = oci_new_connect('u','p','h') or die ("dbdn");
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$r = oci_execute($stid);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

          $result[] = $row;
}
return json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: How do i log this json data onto console as a object

Comment: console.log('<?php echo $your_json ?>')

Answer (score 1):

make array of items and then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate the json as string

```
$items = [];
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        $items[] = $item;
    }
}

$json = json_encode(array("items" => $items))
```